# Custom container with custom iterator doesn't work when container defined as const

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, metaprogramming

More or less everything is in the topic.
when I have

```
func(my_cont& c)
{ c.begin() };
```

things works, but

```
func(const my_cont& c)
{ c.begin() };
```

doesn't work, compiler claims that cant convert this to const my_cont<..>.... from my_cont<..>

What are the requirements for the container and my custom iterator to handle this?

Comment: Do you have a `const` version of `begin()` that returns an iterator that works with `const` container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your container class should have two implementations of begin() and end() - one returning iterator and another returning const_iterator:

```
      iterator begin ();
const_iterator begin () const;
      iterator end ();
const_iterator end () const;
```

const_iterator cannot be used to modify the object that it points to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a const `begin()`, something like this:

```
class my_cont
{
public:
    const_iterator begin() const;
};
```

You'll have to define a `const_iterator` type also.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article on writing iterators:
http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/CUJ_June_2001.pdf

As most people have noted you need a const version of begin() and end() that returns a const_iterator.

What most people have forgotten is that an iterator should be able to implicitly convert into a const_iterator. Otherwise it is hard to get a const iterator from a non cost object (without a lot of nasty casts).

```
 my_cont   data;
 for(my_cont::const_iterator loop = data.begin(); loop != data.end(); ++loop)
 {
     /* STUFF */
 }
```

Note above: The above calls will actually call the non cost versions begin() and end(). But they are being assigned to a const_iterator. So your iterators must be convertible to const_iterator for the above code to work (Note: There is no implicit conversion from const_iterator to iterator. That should take an explicit const_cast as it is inherently dangerous).

```
class my_cont
{
    public:
    class iterator { /* STUFF */ }
    class const_iterator
    {
        public: const_iterator(iterator const& rhs);
        /* STUFF */
    }

    iterator       begin();
    iterator       end();

    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end()   const;
    /* STUFF*/ 
};
```

Comment: Deepest answer here. Thanks. From the linked article by Meyers: "The reason the cast won’t compile is that for these container types, `iterator` and `const_iterator` are completely different classes, barely more closely related to one another than are `string` and `complex<double>`."

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the reason why STL implements cost_iterator for containers. Just check how is it implemented in STL, I'm not sure you can find any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call const member functions on a const object (or volatile member functions on a volatile object).
The compiler is telling that `iterator my_cont::begin() const` is missing.

Comment: `iterator my_cont::begin() const` is insufficient in the same way as `int* pr` cannot be used in `pr = &r` for `const int r`. Needed is `const_iterator` return value (for future operations) and not only `const` of the method `my_cont::begin()` itself.